# Getting a ratio in Pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create another column called "engaged_percent" for each state which is basically the number of unique engaged_count divided by the user_count of each particular state.

I tried doing the following:

```
def f(x):
    engaged_percent = x['engaged_count'].nunique()/x['user_count']
    return pd.Series({'engaged_percent': engaged_percent})

by = df3.groupby(['user_state']).apply(f)
by
```

But it gave me the following result:

[image]

What I want is something like this:

```
user_state        engaged_percent
---------------------------------
California           2/21 = 0.09
Florida              2/7 =  0.28
```

I think my approach is correct , however I am not sure why my result shows up like the one seen in the second picture.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have so many duplicated records in your data frame, is that intentional. And also please don't post image? Just do normal copy and paste, that will make it easier for others to test for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
user_count=df3.groupby('user_state')['user_count'].mean()
#(or however you think a value for each state should be calculated)

engaged_unique=df3.groupby('user_state')['engaged_count'].nunique()

engaged_pct=engaged_unique/user_count
```

(you could also do this in one line in a bunch of different ways)

Your original solution was almost fine except that you were dividing a value by the entire `user count` series. So you were getting a Series instead of a value. You could try this slight variation:

```
def f(x):
    engaged_percent = x['engaged_count'].nunique()/x['user_count'].mean()
    return engaged_percent

by = df3.groupby(['user_state']).apply(f)
by
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just use `groupby` and `apply` directly

```
df3['engaged_percent'] = df3.groupby('user_state')
                            .apply(lambda s: s.engaged_count.nunique()/s.user_count).values
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df3
    engaged_count  user_count  user_state
0               3          21  California
1               3          21  California
2               3          21  California
...
19              4           7     Florida
20              4           7     Florida
21              4           7     Florida

>>> df3['engaged_percent'] = df3.groupby('user_state').apply(lambda s: s.engaged_count.nunique()/s.user_count).values

>>> df3
    engaged_count  user_count  user_state  engaged_percent
0               3          21  California         0.095238
1               3          21  California         0.095238
2               3          21  California         0.095238
...
19              4           7     Florida         0.285714
20              4           7     Florida         0.285714
21              4           7     Florida         0.285714
```

Answer (score 0):

titanic.groupby('Sex')['Fare'].mean()

> you can try this example just put your example in that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is an exact copy, but for the off-topic example, of an already given answer. Please, explain how it is better.