# Find the ratio of rows by column category

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have the following Python pandas dataframe df:

```
 Week |   Category |  Executed
  Wk1         A          0
  Wk1         B          0
  Wk1         C          1
  Wk2         D          1
  Wk2         E          0
```

I want to calculate the ratio of how many categories were executed per week.

End goal dataframe df2:

```
Week |  Exec_Ratio
Wk1        0.3333
Wk2        0.5
```

In Wk1, 1 out of 3 categories were executed – > 1/3 = 0.333 and in Wk2 two 1 out of 2 categories were executed – > 1/2 = 0.5

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322809/getting-a-ratio-in-pandas-groupby-object

Comment: df.groupby(['Week']).Executed.mean()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inferior to @A-Za-z's comment for this specific purpose... however, more generalizable.

```
df.groupby('Week').Executed.agg(dict(Sum='sum', Count='count')).eval('Sum / Count')

Week
Wk1    0.333333
Wk2    0.500000
dtype: float64
```